# Wordpress - Query categories list with advanced custom field argument

Tags: php, wordpress

I use the Advanced Custom Fields plugin which is great to add additional fields to posts or categories but i can't find a solution to add an argument to the get_categories function.

I want to display a list of categories which are child_of=X and a specific custom field must be equal to Y but my code display all of the childs...

```
foreach(get_categories('child_of=4') as $category) {
// Get the icon in a variable
$my_icon = get_cat_icon('echo=false&cat='.$category->cat_ID);
// Display a list with icons and the category names
$value = get_field('ligue');
// Get value of ligue
    if ($value == 1) {
echo '<div class="contentmenupage"><a href="'.get_category_link($category->cat_ID).'">'.$my_icon.'</a><br> <a href="'.get_category_link($category->cat_ID).'" title="'.$category->description.'">'.$category->cat_name.'</a><p>'.get_field('fondation', 'category_' . $category->cat_ID ).'<br>'.get_field('stade', 'category_' . $category->cat_ID ).'<br>'.get_field('couleurs', 'category_' . $category->cat_ID ).'<p></div>';
}
}
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $value = get_field('ligue');
```

You did not put the parameter $category->cat_ID

Check http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/get_field/ for more information.

It should have been something like:

```
    $value = get_field('ligue', $category->cat_ID);
```